# Visual Studio & Xamarin: deploy to Hyper-V emulator failed

Tags: android, deployment, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2015

When I'm trying to run my project Xamarin.Android in Hyper-V with Visual Studio 2015 RC (generally speaking, this error/bug or whatever may occur in different VS versions), I'm getting no deploy process to the emulator. However, the emulator has starting successfully, but nothing deployed into it. After closing the emulator, I'm  getting this message:

> Build Failed: MonoDroid does not support running the previous
>   version. Please ensure your solution builds before running or
>   debugging it.

*My solution is:*

1. Connect to android device in Hyper-V
2. Run in terminal "su root"
3. Run "netcfg" to obtain device ip addrress
4. Then in ADB command prompt type "adb connect 192.168.1.63"
5. After this  VS/Xamarin begins the deploying process and all working fine.
6. End :)

Is this a bug OR can Xamarin/Visual Studio deploy applications (for example, android) to the device emulator automatically?

Comment: I think Xamarin only supports Google's default emulator or Xamarin's own, but not Microsoft's.

Comment: I've been able to deploy without any issues to Microsoft's emulator. I just had to start it from VS 2015.

Comment: Maybe it's my bug...

Comment: @AntonPetrov - did this turn out to be your bug or are you still having trouble with Xamarin-VS Android Emulator deployments?